# how to navigate codes of android frameworks and HAL codes with vim?

Tags: android, vim

Actually, I am a linux kernel engineer and huge vim fan.
I usually browse linux kernel code with cscope, it works great.
But i don't know how to browse android's HAL and frameworks codes.
Cscope acts very bad, it always can't find defination.
Here is my vim-plugin, any suggestion?

```
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-powerline'  
Bundle 'taglist.vim'  
Bundle 'vimwiki'  
Bundle 'SuperTab'  
Bundle 'bufexplorer.zip'  
Bundle 'a.vim'  
Bundle 'slimv.vim'  
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it with Android code, but I have used [eclimd](http://eclim.org/eclimd.html) with other java code and it works great. You can use it with omni-complete, etc.

It is a bit heavyweight though - you run a headless Eclipse server and interact with it through Vim. It also includes a ton of other plugins that modify html, javascript, etc. editing behavior so you have to be aware of that.